# C++11 Template Wrapper class with conversion operator - move semantics

Tags: c++11

I wrote the following class meant to wrap a return value and "forward" that to a call site where the caller shouldn't care about the existence of a wrapper.

```
template<typename T>
class Wrapper
{
  public:
  Wrapper(T&& t) : t(std::forward<T>(t)) {};
  Wrapper(const Wrapper& rhs) : t(std::move(rhs.t)) {};
  ~Wrapper() {};

  operator T() { /* I hook here, e.g. logging, asserting */ return std::move(t); };

  private:
  T t;
};

Wrapper<std::vector<int>> foo()
{
  return std::vector<int>();
}

void bar()
{
  std::vector<int> v = foo();
}
```

Also, at first, I originally wrote

```
operator T() const { return std::move(t); };
```

Doing so, I noticed step debugging sent me into `std::vector(const vector&)` copy constructor and I want to avoid copies.

Can someone please review this? I also had doubts when I wrote `Wrapper(const Wrapper& rhs)` but step debugging with Clang on Mac showed it was actually used (while MSVC 2013 seems to apply RVO even in debug).

Thank you in advance.

PS: interestingly enough, adding `__forceinline` to `operator T()` in MSVC 2013 triggers [C4714](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a98sb923.aspx) (off by default). This leads to me thinking even with moves the generated code is less optimal than I hoped for.

Comment: This bit is confusing: `Wrapper(T&& t) : t(std::forward<T>(t)) {};` Maybe you should rename either the parameter or the member variable.

Comment: @Marshall Not really, this is a common idiom.

Comment: About this part: `Wrapper(const Wrapper& rhs) : t(std::move(rhs.t)) {};`  You can't move from a const - it will always copy.

Comment: Fair enough. Then what's the proper way to move when the compiler doesn't apply RVO?

Comment: its not even RVO here, its standard just move-correctness. You call your compiler editor and puke on him ^_^ Just copy-pasted your example in xcode-clang, and i do go through the Wrapper move-ctor, not the copy-ctor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The move constructor accepts its argument (the moved-from value) as non-`const` because moving from a value may modify that value.

If you declare your `operator T` as `const`, this can no longer happen: `Wrapper::t` is now `const`, and consequently cannot be moved from, only copied.

The same is true for `Wrapper`’s copy constructor, by the way. Do you actually need this? The default copy and move constructors should do just fine for `Wrapper`. You fundamentally cannot force a compiler to perform RVO, although you *can* rely on it as an optimisation. You can*not* rely on it for correctness (meaning, your code must be correct even under the assumption that no RVO is performed).

Comment: Could please show how the compiler generated copy constructor would look like for `Wrapper`? In case RVO is not applied and the compiler decides to make a copy of `Wrapper`, is there a way to avoid a copy of  the wrapped `T`?

Comment: @Gregory There’s no way, no. If the copy constructor is called, a copy is made. And there’s no way to prevent this, by design (well you could have a copy constructor taking its argument by non-`const` ref but that might break semantics, and wouldn’t be callable on a temporary anyway so it wouldn’t help you in the situation you envisage). The whole point is that we *can* under normal circumstances rely on RVO.

Comment: Gregory, that happens in visual studio 2010,(maybe other versons too) its a bug.  Tbe workaround is to add an explicit move constructor.

Answer (score 1):

```
Wrapper(T&& t) : t(std::forward<T>(t)) {};
```

Here you name two different variables `t`, better name them differently.  And then there is no reason to apply `std::forward` here, you already have a rvalue reference.

```
Wrapper(const Wrapper& rhs) : t(std::move(rhs.t)) {};
```

Here you try to move out of a `const` value, because with `rhs` being const, `rhs.t` is const as well.  Won't work, you will get a copy anyway.

This entire exercise appears pretty much pointless.  If you wrap types that do have a move constructor, the compiler will use this for returning anyway.  If you wrap types without move semantics this won't work and you risk an additional copy.  So what's the use case here?

Comment: Without `std::forward` the compiler ends up calling `std::vector`'s copy constructor upon wrapping

Comment: Yep, forward is mandatory if you want the local t to use the move-constructor.

Answer (score 1):

First, RVO only happen in this case:

```
vector<int> foo() {return vector<int>();}
```

To convince you, this example:

```
struct A
{
    A(int v=0) : v(v) {std::cout << "ctor" << std::endl;}
    A(A const& rhs) : v(rhs.v) {std::cout << "cctor" << std::endl;}
    A(A&& rhs) : v(rhs.v) {std::cout << "mctor" << std::endl;}
    int v;
};

A foo() {return A(2);}

int main()
{
    A a = treat(foo());
}
```

returns:

```
$> ctor
```

You do not even go through the move-constructor.
However, when wrapping:

```
template<typename T>
struct ensure_fwd
{
    T t;
    ensure_fwd(T&& t) : t(std::forward<T>(t)) {std::cout << "check" << std::endl;}
    operator T(){return std::move(t);}
};

ensure_fwd<A> foo()
{
    return A();
}
```

This compiles and you get the following output:

```
ctor
mctor
check
mctor
```

Note this is not a very good practice : you loose RVO and get to call twice the move-constructor of A.

As you use a `vector<int>` in your example, I guess you would like to declare your vector, do some push_back, then return it. Keeping the same example, if you define foo like this:

```
ensure_fwd<A> foo() {A a; a.v = 2; return a;}
```

You get a compiler error (I personally get: `No viable conversion from 'A' to ensure_fwd<A>`. That's because we forgot to move our result:

```
ensure_fwd<A> foo() {A a; a.v = 2; return std::move(a);}
```

This compiles and you get the same output as before. Again, ensure_fwd is not very useful and you make two calls to A move-ctor instead of one. You should prefer simply:

```
A foo() {A a; a.v = 2; return std::move(a);}
```

This works the same for a vector, you must not forget the `std::move`, but you can not do the move from outside the function using a wrapper. You can only check it does not copy, but this disable RVO and ensuring no-copy is easily done by putting a move on the return statement.

Comment: I simplified the code before posting. Basically, my use for such a `Wrapper` is to hook into `operator T()` where you can do various things: logging, asserting etc.

Comment: FYI : I used Clang on a Mac for this example.

Comment: OK simplification is the root of all evil ^_^ now I get what you wanted to do. To summarize : remove the copy-constructor if you do not want to copy, this whould works (as it works for me on Clang)

Comment: Sorry you wrote that much :)

Comment: There’s really no sense in calling `std::move` in your last example – in fact, it will prevent NRVO and call one additional move constructor compared to the bare `return a;`.